# Return Struct data type from C-function in Python via SWIG

Tags: python, c, struct, swig, return-type

I have a C-function which returns a **struct** data type with several items in it (size_t, char*, int, unsigned and other structs). When I call this function there is no output in python. After some googling I think the problem is that I didn't declare the data type in my interface file. But this turns out to be not that easy. What is the right approach: **typemaps** or just a simple **typedef**?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to %include the header first. You need the headers for the nested structs too, in dependency order!

After you've done that, Swig should automatically wrap the struct so that a call to your function will return a proxy object with the appropriate members.

A typemap is for when you want to change Swig's default behaviors.

Comment: is it really necessary to define the return data type, or is this just necessary if I want to process the returned value further? What should happen in my case If I just call the function, without specifying any return value, just like `example.foo()` ?

Comment: So you say I don't have to initialize the struct in the interface file when I include the header file in my interface file?

Comment: I think there may be some kind of misunderstanding of how Swig works here. Swig will read and understand your C file, and emit a corresponding Python function. So if you give Swig a C Python that returns a struct, it will write a Python function that returns a proxy to an instance of that struct. Obviously if you discard the return value in Python instead of storing it, that instance will be garbage collected. "initializing the struct" doesn't make any sense - Swig wraps everything it comes across in a %include by default, and at run time instances are constructed as needed.

Comment: Just to make sure I got it right: I only have to define the function I want to use in the interface file and after compiling I just call this function which returns a struct data type. In Python I only have to save the return value, just like this: a = example.foo(), not mentioning a in any way before?

Comment: @Maxi Have you tried it? That is exactly how Swig works. After your line, `a` will be of type "SWIG proxy for struct bar", and you will be able to do `myint = a.someintvalue` to get a Python `int`. Any types in the structure which Swig does not understand will themselves be proxies, of varying levels of utility depending on how well you've told Swig how to wrap them.